# Dependency from django app to jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, python, django, dependencies, pip

I write a reusable django app. This app uses the [are-you-sure](https://plugins.jquery.com/are-you-sure/) jquery library.

## Goal

Installing my app with all dependencies should be easy.

## Use Case

If a developer wants to use my app, then the following line should install the whole app (including the are-you-sure plugin):

```
pip install myreusableapp
```

## Question

What is the common solution to pull in dependency to open source JS code?

## Not part of the question

- Depedencies to other python code gets done via `install_requires` in `setup.py`. Works fine.
- Pushing my django code to pypi is not part of the question. Works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are talking about open-source javascript library you can rely on CDNs (same way you rely on jQuery in your code).

In this specific example - you can use cdnjs for that:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.AreYouSure

Just make sure the template you are using includes the relevant script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.AreYouSure/1.9.0/jquery.are-you-sure.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Dekel said, the easiest solution is to use a third-party CDN.

If, however, you don't want to rely on a third-party CDN, the common solution is to include a copy of the JS library in your app's repository. For example, [django itself does this with jquery](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery). You will need to use the [package_data argument](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#package-data) of `setup()` to include the JS library in your distributable.

Comment: This approach of including a copy of 3rd party component is commonly referred to as "vendoring".